# Human Name parsing

Tags: algorithm, parsing, language-agnostic

I have a bunch of human names.  They are all "Western" names and I only need American conventions/abbreviations (e.g., Mr. instead of Sr. for señor). Unfortunately, the people to whom I am sending things did not input their own names so I can't ask them what they would like to be called.  I know the gender of each person and their full name, but haven't really parsed things out more specifically.

Some examples:

1. John Smith
2. John Smith, Jr.
3. John Smith Jr.
4. John Smith XIV
5. Dr. John Smith, Ph.D.

I'd like to be able to parse out parts of each name:

```
name = Name.new("John Smith Jr.")
name.first_name # <= John
name.greeting   # <= Mr. Smith
```

If I'm looking for "greeting" (probably not the best term), what I want here is, for 1-4, "Mr. Smith".  For 5, I would like Dr. Smith but I'd settle for Mr. Smith.

A Ruby gem for this would be ideal.  I was inspired to ask for something this strange by Chronic, a Ruby gem that handles time in a remarkably human way, letting me correctly tell it "last Tuesday" and having it come up with something sensible." Some algorithm would suffice that hits most of the corner cases.

I'm trying to deal with some of the issues presented in [falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're limited to Western-style names, I think a few rules will get you most of the way there:

1. If a comma appears, delete the leftmost one and everything after.
2. Continue removing words from the beginning while, after converting to lowercase and removing any full stops, they belong to the set `{ mr mrs miss ms rev dr prof }` and any more you can think of.  Using a table of title "scores" (e.g. `[mr=1, mrs=1, rev=2, dr=3, prof=4]` -- order them however you want), record the highest-scoring title that was deleted.
3. Continue removing words from the end while they belong to the set `{ jr phd }` or are Roman numerals of value roughly 50 or less (`/[XVI]+/` is probably a good enough regex).
4. If one or more titles having nonzero scores were deleted in step 2, use the highest-scoring one.  Otherwise, use "Mr." or "Mrs." according to the supplied gender.
5. As the surname, use the last word.

It will never be possible to guarantee that a name like "John Baxter Smith" is parsed correctly, since not all double-barrelled surnames use hyphens.  Is "Baxter Smith" the surname?  Or is "Baxter" a middle name?  I think it's safe to assume that middle names are relatively more common than double-barrelled-but-unhyphenated surnames, meaning it's better to default to reporting the last word as the surname.  You might want to also compile a list of common double-barrelled surnames and check against this, however.

Comment: This gives me a really good starting point for writing my own library to DWIW.  Answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Look on [lufthansa](http://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/New-Registration) page. They ask for them which kind of 'title' they wanna use. I never saw better idea like that.

I don't recommend use gem or whatever in this case because english/spanish/french/.... there are difference on gender, then, if you try discover by yourself, you can't be successful.

I hope help you

Comment: This is definitely the right answer if you're starting afresh, but it might be that the system has already been in existence for some time.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if I could ask these people anything at all.  Unfortunately I have to take a best guess. Note my question also asks about distinguishing John Smith XIV => Mr. Smith, rather than Mr. XIV.  Like I said in the question, I already know the gender separately.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Perl based parser available to do this type of extraction http://search.cpan.org/~kimryan/Lingua-EN-NameParse/

I ran it through your examples to get the following results.It only handles ordinal suffixes up to 12 (XII) and also does not recognise the . in Ph.D so I had to change this in your input data

```
JOHN SMITH                                John                             Smith                       
JOHN SMITH, JR.                           John                             Smith                Jr     
JOHN SMITH JR.                            John                             Smith                Jr     
JOHN SMITH XII                            John                             Smith                XII    
DR. JOHN SMITH, PHD              Dr.      John                             Smith                Phd
```

Answer (score 1):

humanparser

Parse a human name string into salutation, first name, middle name, last name, suffix.

Install

```
npm install humanparser
```

Usage

```
var human = require('humanparser');

var fullName = 'Mr. William R. Jenkins, III'
    , attrs = human.parseName(fullName);

console.log(attrs);

//produces the following output

{ saluation: 'Mr.',
  firstName: 'William',
  suffix: 'III',
  lastName: 'Jenkins',
  middleName: 'R.',
  fullName: 'Mr. William R. Jenkins, III' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Ruby gem [Namae](https://github.com/berkmancenter/namae)?

It should deal with most western names well and comes with a couple of configuration options for tricky scenarios (multiple last names, comma used both to separate names in a list and name parts). Having said that, it's a deterministic parser (using this [grammar](https://github.com/berkmancenter/namae/blob/master/lib/namae/parser.y)) and there are some cases it won't cover.

Here is your example:

```
require('namae')

Namae.parse 'John Smith and John Smith, Jr. and John Smith Jr and John Smith XIV'
#=> [
  #<Name family="Smith" given="John">,
  #<Name family="Smith" given="John" suffix="Jr.">,
  #<Name family="Smith" given="John" suffix="Jr">,
  #<Name family="Smith" given="John" suffix="XIV">
]
```

It struggles with the doctor's title, but that's something we might be able to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [parser.name](https://parser.name/)?

Parsing names is complex so I would recommend to use an [API service that parses names into components](https://parser.name/name-parsing/).
You can integrate the RESTful API into your project or use the web app to run a list in your browser.
This way you are sure you get the first and last name and its even validated and contains more details like salutation, nationality and gender.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a (very) old question, but I ended up having the same problem, so thought I'd contribute my solution.

Regex- and grammar-based approaches can do a fine job if your data is clean and US-only. However, if your names are merely in the latin writing system, then purely syntactic approaches tend to break down, even if all the names follow [western naming traditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name#Western_name_order). Consider the following:

- Initials, e.g., J. R. R. Tolkien, J. Edgar Hoover, etc.
- Double-barreled names, e.g., Jean-Pierre Flamel, Catherine Zeta-Jones
- Particles in names, e.g., Fernando de la Vega, Bashar al Assad
- Middle name versus second last name ambiguity, e.g., Juan García Lopez

I really like the article you linked! I'll add another that discusses some of the above ideas: [What's in a Name?](https://www.humangraphics.io/blog/whats-in-a-name-part-1-introduction)

If you find the regex-based approach breaks down, then the next best best is a data-driven solution that uses a [statistical parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_parsing) to decode names. These tools don't make any syntactic assumptions about case, name order (i.e., [western](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name#Western_name_order) versus [eastern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_name#Eastern_name_order) order), and so on. Instead, they use a large database of real names to perform pattern matching instead. It's these approaches that allow them to resolve ambiguities, recognize particles in names, and so on. These systems often produce demographic estimates as well as structured name data, which you could use to enrich and/or verify the parse of your names (since you already have gender).

If you need a data-driven name parser, then [HumanGraphics](https://www.humangraphics.io/) is a good option. Its [name parser](https://www.humangraphics.io/features/names) is based on name data describing 7 billion people, and it reliably parses names in a wide variety of writing systems and naming traditions.

Disclaimer: I built HumanGraphics, and for exactly the reasons you're citing!