# Is there lib or some old method to get names from string?

Tags: javascript

I have string:

```
var fullText = 'John,victor and Mike and not Rudie';
```

Is there way or library in js to get names from such a string?
UPDATE: in case if I know that other text except 'and',  ','  'not' are names. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define a name? Every name a person on this planet could possibly have?

Comment: No, there is not, because **you cannot make any assumptions about names**: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: updated question maybe this will helps?

Comment: `old method`? :O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var fullText = 'John,victor and Mike and not Rudie';
fullText = fullText.replace(" and ", ",");
fullText = fullText.replace(" and not ", ",");
fullText = fullText.split(",");
console.log("name1: " + fullText[0] + " name2: " + fullText[1] + " name3: " + fullText[2] + " name4: " + fullText[3]);
```

Use `replace` and `split`
If number of names is unknow you can do the same thing just by adding `for` or `while`.

Example:

```js
var fullText = 'John,victor and Mike and not Rudie';
fullText = fullText.replace(" and ", ",");
fullText = fullText.replace(" and not ", ",");
fullText = fullText.split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < fullText.length; i++) {
    console.log("name" + (i + 1) + ": " + fullText[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that there is a library for this cause this needs NLP which is not easy to implement. But, you can define a list(like in a file or enumeration ) of names (base on your definition of name) and then check if a token is a name or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: if you want to extract names out of article for example and not from a fixed text formula;

there are researches that worth to look into:

**Google for** :Human Name Parser, Named Entity Recognition (NER), human names parser api

[Onyxfish](https://gist.github.com/onyxfish/322906)
[Humaniformat](https://github.com/Ironholds/humaniformat)

[Human Name parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17455658/7735285)

I guess in all cases there should be a dictionary .

**This one is also very interesting:**

https://www.nameapi.org/

an API to get Names and gender.